# I need to get the first log in database and determine how many minutes late and sum it up. java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, wampserver

Here's an example of my database

-table records

```
name    loginDate     loginTime  
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  
Chin    2015-01-02    10:00  
Chris   2015-01-02    10:09  
Chin    2015-01-03    8:00  
Chin    2015-01-03    9:00  
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01  
Chris   2015-01-03    9:03
```

-table employee

```
name    startingTime  
Chin    8:30  
Chris   9:00
```

so basically, I need a query that can return only the first log-in in the day and determine if he's late by comparing the startingTime in another table and get their minutes late. the return value should be:

```
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  30
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  40
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01  1
```

I use this code to determine the first login and minutes late:

```
SELECT t.name, t.logindate, t.loginTime, timestampdiff(minute, t1.startingTime, 
t.loginTime) as is_late 
FROM 
(   SELECT name, loginDate, TIME(MIN(loginTime)) as loginTime
    FROM records  
   GROUP BY name, loginDate
) t 
JOIN employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name
HAVING is_late > 0
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how can I sum up all the minutes late for each name. the return value should be like this:

```
name    date          logIn minLate  totalMinLate
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  30       30
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  40       41
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01  1        41
```

Or you can just give me a good other way to have a total minutes late without redundancy by each name.

PS. I'm using java netbeans

If you can give me a query that can help me get the exact return value i need, thank you!

Comment: you can try using cursor

Comment: what do you mean by cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this statement is valid:

```
SELECT t.name, t.logindate, t.loginTime, if(timestampdiff(minute, 
t1.startingTime, t.loginTime) > 0, timestampdiff(minute, t1.startingTime, 
t.loginTime), 0) as minLate 
FROM 
(   SELECT name, loginDate, TIME(MIN(loginTime)) as loginTime
    FROM records  
   GROUP BY name, loginDate
) t 
JOIN employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name
HAVING is_late > 0
```

Could you then run something like:

```
SELECT name, logindate, sum(minLate)
from (
SELECT t.name, t.logindate, t.loginTime, if(timestampdiff(minute, 
t1.startingTime, t.loginTime) > 0, timestampdiff(minute, t1.startingTime, 
t.loginTime), 0) as minLate 
FROM 
(   SELECT name, loginDate, TIME(MIN(loginTime)) as loginTime
    FROM records  
   GROUP BY name, loginDate
) t 
JOIN employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name
HAVING is_late > 0) 
group by name, logindate
```

Comment: i got an error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Already worked but still didn't sum up all minutes late. It just copy the minLate

Comment: It is summing by loginDate.  If you want it summed by user, then take logindate out of the select and group by clauses

Comment: I made an alias name only after the having part

Comment: so it can't be group by both name and logindate? I got an output 1 name and all their total late. It can't be all the day they were late and still sums it up?

Comment: Well....  you may be able to do it with a cartesian join between the query you started with that returns the dates and minutes late joined on name to the query that sums the minutes and groups by name.

Comment: Ok thank you sir! I did another way to solve the problem hehe